# Python+Firebird Dynamic SQL Error Token Unknown

Tags: python, sql, syntax-error, firebird

When I connect to a Firebird database and try to execute a query, it throws me this error:

```
    "Error while preparing SQL statement:")
fdb.fbcore.DatabaseError: ('Error while preparing SQL statement:\n- SQLCODE: -104\n- Dynamic SQL Error\n- SQL error code = -104\n- Token unknown - line 27, column 113\n- )', -104, 335544569)
```

My query looks like:

```
select distinct p.ID, p.DATE, p.PETITION, pac.KEY, ..., 
  pac.BIRTH_DATE, trunc(('today' - pac.BIRTH_DATE)/365.25) as AGE, p.NAME,...
```

And I've checked that the cause of the error is:

```
trunc(('today' - pac.BIRTH_DATE)/365.25) as AGE
```

if I remove it from the query, it works perfectly. Anyone knows why? Could you help me?

I've done what @ain told me:

```
trunc((cast(CURRENT_DATE - pac.BIRTH_DATE) as DOUBLE PRECISION)/365.25) as AGE

    "Error while preparing SQL statement:")
fdb.fbcore.DatabaseError: ('Error while preparing SQL statement:\n- SQLCODE: -104\n- Dynamic SQL Error\n- SQL error code = -104\n- Database SQL dialect 1 does not support reference to DATE datatype', -104, 335544569)
```

But this results in the same error. Also if I try:

```
 DATEDIFF(YEAR from CURRENT_DATE to pac.BIRTH_DATE) as AGE

    "Error while preparing SQL statement:")
fdb.fbcore.DatabaseError: (
     'Error while preparing SQL statement:\n-
      SQLCODE: -104\n- 
      Dynamic SQL Error\n- 
      SQL error code = -104\n- 
      Database SQL dialect 1 does not support reference to DATE datatype',
   -104, 335544569)
```

Finally I solved the issue by doing:

```
... trunc(DATEDIFF(DAY from cast(pac.BIRTH_DATE as DATE) to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)/365.25) as AGE ...
```

I'll take a look to dialects too. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Have you noticed that the error is now different: `"Database SQL dialect 1 does not support reference to DATE datatype"`. Why do you use dialect 1 ?

Comment: The last problem should be fixed by using `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` instead of `CURRENT_DATE`, dialect 1 datatype `DATE` is actually a timestamp, so `CURRENT_DATE` doesn't work as it has an unknown datatype for dialect 1.

Comment: Hello @MarkRotteveel Thank you for your comment, it fixed the problem!

Answer (score 0):

You have to cast `'today'` to date, otherwise it is just a string literal. Ie use

```
... trunc((cast('today' as date) - pac.BIRTH_DATE)/365.25) as AGE ...
```

You might also want to use `CURRENT_DATE` instead, see [Context variables](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-functions-contextvars.html) topic of the Firebird manual.

It seems you want to calculate age in "full years" so you could use `DATEDIFF` function for that:

```
DATEDIFF(YEAR from CURRENT_DATE to pac.BIRTH_DATE)
```

Comment: Given the op is using dialect 1, use of `CURRENT_DATE` should be avoided, and instead `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` should be used.

Answer (score 0):

You are not supposed to use Dialect 1. It was obsoleted with releases of Interbase 6 and Firebird 0.9 in 2000. It is sole intention is backward compatibility with pre-2000 database server versions for pre-2000 legacy applications. In 2018 this purpose has little practical value and hence Dialect 1 not only blocks you from using most recent language and engine enhancements, but maybe outright buggy due to little real world exposure thus little out of the house testing.

You have to migrate your database to Dialect 3. Checking and ironing out all the incompatibilities that the database creator maybe introduced to it, coding it by pre-2000 language, along your migration.

- http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq24/
- http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq186/
- https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-background.html